# On top of itself

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What's the word I'm looking for?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The word you are looking for is:

> **FOLD**

Because if you...

> ...treat the red lines as creases and the white spaces as transparent, it is possible to fold the grids in a way that eventually you are left with black shapes in an arrangement that spells out the word:
>
>  [image: FOLD spelled out by black squares]
>
>  This of course makes literal use of the title.

Step by step:

> [image: Step by step folds]